# Iteration over two list of different lengths in python

Tags: python-3.x

So my question is would it be possible to iterate over two list of different lengths. While continuously iterating over the small list until the length of the longer list is reached?
To further explain with an example.

say I have a two list
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
nums2 = [1,2,3,4]

is it possible to iterate over the two list to obtain an output of
output: [1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,1
6,2
7,3]

so basically when it reaches the end of the smaller list it just starts from the beginning of the smaller list but continues until it hits the end of the longer list

Comment: What should be the result if nums and nums2 were switched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [use `itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to infinitely repeat the shorter input, then `zip` it with the longer input (`zip` stops when the longer input completes), e.g.:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> list(zip(nums, cycle(nums2)))
[(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 1), (6, 2), (7, 3)]
```

Comment: Obviously, if you don't know one of them will always be the longest, you precheck lengths and only wrap the shorter one in `cycle`.