# "NameError: name 'number' is not defined" - working with lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, nameerror

I made a code with the for-loop in Python, and I cannot get it right.
So, Python receives two lists from me. One is named colors and contains the seven colors of the rainbow, while the other one is named crayons_count and contains seven numbers that would represent how many crayons you have from each color.

The problem is, I worked in the code with 2 for-loops. And in the second one, I get a NameError. I have been researching this problem for days.

So, this is my code:

```
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']
crayons_count = [10, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3]

for index, color in enumerate(colors):
    print(index, color)

for (color) in colors and (number) in crayons_count:
    print (color, number)
```

And I was expecting to get something like this:

```
0 red
1 orange
2 yellow
3 green
4 blue
5 indigo
6 violet
red 10
orange 5
yellow 7
green 8
blue 9
indigo 2
violet 3
```

For now, I have the results of the first loop but get this error from the second loop:

[This is an image with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXEwx.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iteration over two list of different lengths in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322994/iteration-over-two-list-of-different-lengths-in-python)

Comment: You get a NameError because the variable *number* is not in scope

Answer (score 0):

You can use zip method

```
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']
crayons_count = [10, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3]

for index, color in enumerate(colors):
    print(index, color)

for (number, color) in zip(crayons_count, colors):
    print(color, number)
```

output

```
0 red
1 orange
2 yellow
3 green
4 blue
5 indigo
6 violet
red 10
orange 5
yellow 7
green 8
blue 9
indigo 2
violet 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single loop by building a list then, finally, just one call to *print()*

```
colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']
crayons_count = [10, 5, 7, 8, 9, 2, 3]

a = []

for i, (color, count) in enumerate(zip(colors, crayons_count)):
    a.insert(i, f'{i} {color}')
    a.append(f'{color} {count}')

print(*a, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
0 red
1 orange
2 yellow
3 green
4 blue
5 indigo
6 violet
red 10
orange 5
yellow 7
green 8
blue 9
indigo 2
violet 3
```